# How do i add the option to mute/unmute and the option of playback on AVPlayer Swift

Tags: swift, uikit, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

Im having an issue where once the View loads the video starts playing automatically as intended but the user doesn't have the option to mute the video. How do you add the option to mute/unmute and have the playback option on the video itself. [Heres a snippet of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly4fL.png)

Comment: Please do not give screenshots of code. Just put the relevant code in the question, ideally as a minimally runnable example.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  Screenshots are extremely difficult to work with and unreadable by screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AVplayer's volume property to control the audio. Setting it's value to 0 will mute the audio, you can also use `isMuted=true` to mute

More about that here
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1390127-volume

Comment: Will the user be able to mute the volume on their own or do i have to add a button on top of the video for the user to be able to mute the video?

Comment: I think you need to add a button which controls the audio using those properties